# Scroll View Items Come Over the Navigation Bar in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, navigationbar, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-scrollview

I made a custom *nav bar*. and added a scroll view below it. The problem I am getting is when I *scroll down*, the **data** inside *scroll view* comes over the navigation bar. Here is the screenshot:

[image: scroll view image]

My code is:

```
struct NewsfeedView: View {
    
    var newsfeedModel: [NewsFeedData]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            CustomNavBar(navTitle: "Newsfeed")
            
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack{
                    ForEach(newsfeedModel) { modelData in
                         
                        NewsFeedTableViewCell(newsFedd: modelData)
          }
        }
      }
    }.ignoresSafeArea()
  }
}
```

Does anyone knows what is the issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If it's undesired then just clip it, like

```
ScrollView {
  // .. content here
}
.clipped()    // << here !!
```

Comment: Perfect! it's works on both iOS and MacOS

Comment: This workaround has at least one side effect (and possibly more): The content doesn't appear to blur or otherwise go "under" the navigation bar as one would expect.

It is, indeed, simply clipped.

Comment: perfect solution. are you hero? :) You save my day.